# How to inject a value into a Monoid?

Tags: haskell

It just appeared to me that there is no way to inject a single value into a Monoid in `Data.Monoid`. I hesitate to use `Data.Monad.return` for this but was hoping to find something like `singleton` for several types.

Comment: A `Monoid` is just a type with a `Monoid` instance, it's not a container (in general) into which you inject values. For example there is an `instance Monoid Ordering`, and for that you have the three (non-bottom) values `LT`, `EQ`, `GT`, there's nothing to inject, just write the value.

Comment: What type would it have? `singleton :: Monoid m => a -> ???`

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov `singleton x = mempty` :) (very useful)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Monoid` class does not allow for any kind of injection since the monoid is not any kind of container.  Some containers are monoids, and then they will have their own means for injection.  For a relatively general injection you can use `pure` from `Applicative`, or `return` from `Monad` (the former is more general).

Comment: Hmm ... so ... is there a theoretical grounded class that wraps up `Containers`?

Comment: @Florian: type constructors having this "inject" operation, but not necessarily `Applicative`, a called [`Pointed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pointed/3.0.3/doc/html/Data-Pointed.html).

Answer (score 6):

Adding to what others have said: `Int` forms a monoid (in several different ways). How would you "inject" a value into `Int`? Well, you don't; an `Int` is just an `Int`. You could maybe use zero or something...?

Now, if something *is* a container, it forms a monoid. But the monoid bit doesn't help you treat it as a container; you need to try something else for that. Lots of things that aren't containers form monoids.